# cygwin, cygstart, unix path to windows 8 char paths

Tags: unix, window, cygwin

I am using perl under cygwin to run imagemagick and LaTeX. For various reasons, I must run pdflatex under cygstart. I have a path with spaces in the cygstart command, and only run this correctly with a windows path without space

```
cygstart c:/stuff/pdflatex.exe c:/Users/mainho~1/Pictures/6-13/directory.tex

mainho~1" is the 8char form of "main home computer
```

I would like a perl or unix function which would take

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/main\ home\ computer/Pictures/6-13/directory.tex
```

and would return

```
c:/Users/mainho~1/Pictures/6-13/directory.tex
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cygpath` command in a shell to convert between both formats of paths

Convert from Windows path to unix.

```
cygpath "D:\\tmp"
```

Note that I use double backslashes because it needs to be escaped as it has a special meaning.

Convert from unix to Windows

```
cygpath -w "/usr/bin"
```

Comment: Actually you have these backwards.  the `-w` switch will convert from unix to windows, so your two examples do nothing.  They should be `cygpath -w "/usr/bin"` and `cygpath "D:\\tmp"`

Comment: Preceding slash is not required by `cygpath` itself, it is required by shell. You can use single quotes in bash to eliminated one slash.

Answer (score 0):

Bash:
`cygpath -m '/cygwin/c/Users`
would return
`c:/Users`
. `-m` stands for "mixed" meaning that forward slashes are used with volume identifiers.

If you launch it without shell you should drop single quotes.

I do not remember whether using single quotes makes same difference in Perl, try it yourself.